SUMPRODUCT arrays different sheets and length
I am struggling with sumproduct.  I have two tables, one of which represents individuals and the other which represents projections over a period of time.
For each row in table1, I need the sumproduct of columns "factor," "weight," "reduction," and "discount" (where state = state, sex = sex, and age between age and maxage) and from table2 columns "rate" and "count" (where age in table2 = age in table1 and time in table2 <=maxage+1 in table1).
In essence, I want
=SUMPRODUCT(($C$2:$C$2801>=C2)*($C$2:$C$2801<=H2)*($A$2:$A$2801=A2)*($B$2:$B$2801=B2)*($D$2:$D$2801)*($E$2:$E$2801)*($F$2:$F$2801)*($G$2:$G$2801),(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$5051=$C2)*(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5051<=$H2+1)*(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$5051)*(Sheet2!$D$2:$D$5051))
That won't work though because arrays are of different lengths, even though after processing the "if" conditions, the arrays are actually the same length.  I managed to find a way to get to the solution, but because the multipliers (the values in those other columns) are controlled by other choices, when it has to calculate, it's basically useless (even with only ~50k rows).
Here are the two ways I made it work (they're basically the same thing):
=SUMPRODUCT(FILTER(FILTER($A$2:$H$2801,($C$2:$C$2801>=C2)*($C$2:$C$2801<=H2)*($A$2:$A$2801=A2)*($B$2:$B$2801=B2),""),($A$1:$H$1="factor"),""),FILTER(FILTER($A$2:$H$2801,($C$2:$C$2801>=C2)*($C$2:$C$2801<=H2)*($A$2:$A$2801=A2)*($B$2:$B$2801=B2),""),($A$1:$H$1="weight"),""),FILTER(FILTER($A$2:$H$2801,($C$2:$C$2801>=C2)*($C$2:$C$2801<=H2)*($A$2:$A$2801=A2)*($B$2:$B$2801=B2),""),($A$1:$H$1="reduction"),""),FILTER(FILTER($A$2:$H$2801,($C$2:$C$2801>=C2)*($C$2:$C$2801<=H2)*($A$2:$A$2801=A2)*($B$2:$B$2801=B2),""),($A$1:$H$1="discount"),""),FILTER(FILTER(Sheet2!$A$2:$D$5051,((Sheet2!$B$2:$B$5051=$C2)*(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5051<=$H2+1)),""),(Sheet2!$A$1:$D$1="rate"),""),FILTER(FILTER(Sheet2!$A$2:$D$5051,((Sheet2!$B$2:$B$5051=$C2)*(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5051<=$H2+1)),""),(Sheet2!$A$1:$D$1="count"),""))
Or using LET(
=LET(Array1,FILTER($A$2:$H$2801,(($C$2:$C$2801>=$C2)*($C$2:$C$2801<=$H2)*($B$2:$B$2801=$B2)*($A$2:$A$2801=$A2)),""),Array1A,FILTER(Array1,($A$1:$H$1="factor"),""),Array1B,FILTER(Array1,($A$1:$H$1="weight"),""),Array1C,FILTER(Array1,($A$1:$H$1="reduction"),""),Array1D,FILTER(Array1,($A$1:$H$1="discount"),""),Array2,FILTER(Sheet2!$A$2:$D$5051,((Sheet2!$B$2:$B$5051=$C2)*(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5051<=$H2+1)),""),Array2A,FILTER(Array2,(Sheet2!$A$1:$D$1="rate"),""),Array2B,FILTER(Array2,(Sheet2!$A$1:$D$1="count"),""),SUMPRODUCT(Array1A,Array1B,Array1C,Array1D,Array2A,Array2B))
The original workbook relied on a massive amount of OFFSET and INDIRECT functions which made it so slow it was unusable, so I was asked to find a better way.  They want it without using VBA, though I'm starting to think that won't be happening.  The only other idea I have is a lot more columns.

Data in text format:
Table1:



state
sex
age
factor
weight
reduction
discount
maxage




1
M
0
0.7957
0.4980
0.9170
0.4596
49


1
F
0
0.2008
0.3557
0.0816
0.3990
49


1
M
1
0.5983
0.9033
0.5879
0.0524
50


1
F
1
0.7206
0.2295
0.7398
0.6234
50


1
M
2
0.8212
0.1305
0.9636
0.9022
51


1
F
2
0.7178
0.0695
0.4151
0.5309
51


1
M
3
0.6068
0.2600
0.3310
0.9246
52


1
F
3
0.4028
0.4878
0.8218
0.8845
52


1
M
4
0.4023
0.8970
0.7233
0.8899
53


1
F
4
0.6086
0.8829
0.6756
0.5227
53


1
M
5
0.8983
0.9794
0.9420
0.4846
54


1
F
5
0.4418
0.5399
0.6250
0.9139
54


1
M
6
0.9268
0.9799
0.3462
0.3355
55


1
F
6
0.8064
0.0868
0.0868
0.0392
55


1
M
7
0.5930
0.2939
0.7156
0.0472
56


1
F
7
0.1341
0.4783
0.1174
0.6005
56


1
M
8
0.3694
0.3643
0.0273
0.7473
57


1
F
8
0.9917
0.8983
0.0994
0.1636
57


1
M
9
0.6905
0.4604
0.1318
0.5900
58


1
F
9
0.2651
0.0067
0.5714
0.2866
58


1
M
10
0.3149
0.8735
0.2050
0.6325
59


1
F
10
0.3302
0.6756
0.9428
0.0487
59


1
M
11
0.2898
0.4101
0.0536
0.3884
60


1
F
11
0.0164
0.2335
0.3769
0.5946
60


1
M
12
0.2871
0.3553
0.0799
0.8853
61


1
F
12
0.9612
0.2316
0.7813
0.2725
61


1
M
13
0.4145
0.0722
0.6584
0.7030
62


1
F
13
0.8787
0.7817
0.8555
0.7145
62


1
M
14
0.9767
0.7314
0.0115
0.2084
63


1
F
14
0.3699
0.2813
0.1800
0.7543
63


1
M
15
0.5354
0.5422
0.2838
0.2006
64


1
F
15
0.3255
0.8546
0.6598
0.7013
64


1
M
16
0.2456
0.0066
0.2436
0.5083
65


1
F
16
0.5739
0.6858
0.7770
0.6331
65


1
M
17
0.4126
0.5348
0.5408
0.1089
66


1
F
17
0.6931
0.1754
0.1277
0.4392
66


1
M
18
0.2292
0.8879
0.7626
0.1920
67


1
F
18
0.4606
0.9366
0.1429
0.0688
67


1
M
19
0.7928
0.7069
0.1766
0.7200
68


1
F
19
0.8572
0.2292
0.1528
0.9456
68


1
M
20
0.3414
0.6847
0.1112
0.1189
69


1
F
20
0.2561
0.0773
0.2428
0.5654
69


1
M
21
0.7547
0.1034
0.6747
0.4381
70


1
F
21
0.6170
0.1195
0.2079
0.5468
70


1
M
22
0.4329
0.0193
0.2065
0.0488
71


1
F
22
0.7754
0.8698
0.7612
0.0371
71


1
M
23
0.3127
0.4153
0.3801
0.4435
72


1
F
23
0.3031
0.9583
0.3996
0.9373
72


1
M
24
0.8590
0.8720
0.3075
0.3842
73


1
F
24
0.7655
0.7745
0.4828
0.7160
73


1
M
25
0.2967
0.8740
0.8525
0.5149
74


1
F
25
0.6406
0.6007
0.7917
0.2942
74


1
M
26
0.9432
0.2151
0.5174
0.9982
75


1
F
26
0.5200
0.1804
0.9816
0.1526
75


1
M
27
0.2239
0.0513
0.5230
0.1895
76


1
F
27
0.6825
0.3759
0.2101
0.8002
76


1
M
28
0.9120
0.1104
0.8375
0.4193
77


1
F
28
0.9855
0.5889
0.0176
0.0022
77


1
M
29
0.7930
0.4171
0.3524
0.9897
78


1
F
29
0.8898
0.0630
0.3922
0.1569
78


1
M
30
0.0008
0.1787
0.4106
0.8365
79


1
F
30
0.6469
0.1740
0.2713
0.7087
79


1
M
31
0.1305
0.4952
0.4934
0.4547
80


1
F
31
0.3927
0.3425
0.0798
0.5515
80


1
M
32
0.0631
0.4752
0.8618
0.0294
81


1
F
32
0.5705
0.4235
0.4713
0.6354
81


1
M
33
0.6276
0.9440
0.8247
0.5009
82


1
F
33
0.9457
0.7762
0.3957
0.5668
82


1
M
34
0.7205
0.8169
0.9580
0.3159
83


1
F
34
0.7470
0.6488
0.3646
0.5119
83


1
M
35
0.9689
0.3198
0.1618
0.9052
84


1
F
35
0.0756
0.5904
0.6566
0.1866
84


1
M
36
0.0951
0.0367
0.3816
0.0206
85


1
F
36
0.6966
0.1578
0.3774
0.8003
85


1
M
37
0.3447
0.3749
0.6322
0.8062
86


1
F
37
0.3428
0.0014
0.9759
0.4879
86


1
M
38
0.3115
0.3269
0.2346
0.4383
87


1
F
38
0.2194
0.8558
0.9019
0.6719
87


1
M
39
0.2576
0.9518
0.7497
0.3449
88


1
F
39
0.5380
0.9637
0.5033
0.4090
88


1
M
40
0.1279
0.1252
0.4894
0.9661
89


1
F
40
0.9104
0.6723
0.1028
0.2755
89


1
M
41
0.6379
0.0242
0.0209
0.8563
90


1
F
41
0.9946
0.8064
0.6217
0.3561
90


1
M
42
0.7912
0.5899
0.0024
0.3164
91


1
F
42
0.5724
0.8061
0.5053
0.8788
91


1
M
43
0.4280
0.0754
0.8396
0.8048
92


1
F
43
0.3212
0.9045
0.3943
0.4917
92


1
M
44
0.0845
0.0535
0.8778
0.4514
93


1
F
44
0.8473
0.7502
0.0174
0.8584
93


1
M
45
0.3555
0.4436
0.6478
0.6568
94


1
F
45
0.2409
0.8095
0.0973
0.3967
94


1
M
46
0.6532
0.5990
0.0813
0.4915
95


1
F
46
0.9742
0.4480
0.2095
0.2652
95


1
M
47
0.1548
0.4953
0.6552
0.2235
96


1
F
47
0.4013
0.2882
0.5390
0.1640
96


1
M
48
0.5892
0.6052
0.4248
0.1052
97


1
F
48
0.6974
0.3510
0.5457
0.7994
97


1
M
49
0.7870
0.2494
0.3732
0.1273
98


1
F
49
0.0538
0.5521
0.5521
0.0258
98


1
M
50
0.8056
0.9861
0.2525
0.9693
99


1
F
50
0.4744
0.4778
0.3033
0.6072
99


1
M
51
0.0398
0.7826
0.0863
0.9923
99


1
F
51
0.7974
0.7108
0.6843
0.6588
99


1
M
52
0.5463
0.7067
0.9859
0.4297
99


1
F
52
0.2994
0.8243
0.4728
0.3745
99


1
M
53
0.5349
0.4515
0.1269
0.6390
99


1
F
53
0.3042
0.8616
0.7203
0.7576
99


1
M
54
0.2359
0.4676
0.5340
0.0299
99


1
F
54
0.8776
0.5002
0.5479
0.7780
99


1
M
55
0.0869
0.3062
0.8203
0.7340
99


1
F
55
0.6615
0.6736
0.1126
0.5204
99


1
M
56
0.9670
0.8136
0.3311
0.8867
99


1
F
56
0.0219
0.0177
0.7908
0.3347
99


1
M
57
0.7264
0.2233
0.0511
0.8241
99


1
F
57
0.6730
0.4151
0.1249
0.3139
99


1
M
58
0.6517
0.4191
0.6208
0.3334
99


1
F
58
0.7833
0.8275
0.4089
0.9592
99


1
M
59
0.2095
0.1054
0.7013
0.1948
99


1
F
59
0.3358
0.3297
0.5294
0.7569
99


1
M
60
0.7945
0.4479
0.6747
0.1205
99


1
F
60
0.7108
0.8551
0.1333
0.5054
99


1
M
61
0.1639
0.4600
0.4237
0.1874
99


1
F
61
0.6221
0.5362
0.5914
0.4069
99


1
M
62
0.2972
0.0614
0.9168
0.9374
99


1
F
62
0.4340
0.6810
0.0464
0.9163
99


1
M
63
0.3056
0.9890
0.7877
0.6442
99


1
F
63
0.5711
0.5070
0.0062
0.1128
99


1
M
64
0.8967
0.6126
0.0928
0.2155
99


1
F
64
0.3442
0.8042
0.3836
0.2091
99


1
M
65
0.9119
0.5047
0.3057
0.6501
99


1
F
65
0.4162
0.0121
0.1459
0.7396
99


1
M
66
0.7470
0.5106
0.4433
0.3711
99


1
F
66
0.3023
0.8532
0.9271
0.1690
99


1
M
67
0.9098
0.0914
0.8446
0.0067
99


1
F
67
0.7808
0.9800
0.5828
0.5608
99


1
M
68
0.9954
0.3225
0.3479
0.5003
99


1
F
68
0.2910
0.0479
0.4062
0.6020
99


1
M
69
0.1458
0.7088
0.2541
0.1339
99


1
F
69
0.9312
0.9958
0.7950
0.6563
99


1
M
70
0.4112
0.7964
0.8269
0.6656
99


1
F
70
0.4195
0.4734
0.8683
0.7143
99


1
M
71
0.4589
0.7282
0.1307
0.7893
99


1
F
71
0.6797
0.3022
0.2576
0.5909
99


1
M
72
0.4391
0.0428
0.4384
0.6768
99


1
F
72
0.4969
0.6370
0.2032
0.5161
99


1
M
73
0.5485
0.7097
0.6174
0.7546
99


1
F
73
0.2372
0.9470
0.0484
0.9870
99


1
M
74
0.2333
0.2928
0.8055
0.4566
99


1
F
74
0.6735
0.2233
0.2585
0.8916
99


1
M
75
0.5468
0.6144
0.2388
0.3563
99


1
F
75
0.2971
0.6148
0.8142
0.3275
99


1
M
76
0.1922
0.7148
0.0384
0.4299
99


1
F
76
0.7629
0.5541
0.0688
0.9359
99


1
M
77
0.4778
0.3232
0.6505
0.1128
99


1
F
77
0.7858
0.6621
0.4187
0.8894
99


1
M
78
0.3535
0.0825
0.2073
0.2781
99


1
F
78
0.7410
0.5556
0.9437
0.2914
99


1
M
79
0.3386
0.7507
0.0878
0.2395
99


1
F
79
0.2396
0.8908
0.6167
0.7586
99


1
M
80
0.8759
0.5434
0.0879
0.6403
99


1
F
80
0.0258
0.0499
0.3278
0.4435
99


1
M
81
0.4431
0.5692
0.5278
0.5958
99


1
F
81
0.0919
0.6465
0.4029
0.1215
99


1
M
82
0.9851
0.7001
0.3626
0.0696
99


1
F
82
0.9261
0.9287
0.5429
0.4419
99


1
M
83
0.0408
0.8946
0.6268
0.2279
99


1
F
83
0.7061
0.0729
0.4826
0.2257
99


1
M
84
0.0438
0.0938
0.2744
0.8262
99


1
F
84
0.5651
0.1119
0.7386
0.3289
99


1
M
85
0.9410
0.1126
0.0150
0.7631
99


1
F
85
0.9167
0.7321
0.3353
0.7482
99


1
M
86
0.0787
0.7811
0.9083
0.5035
99


1
F
86
0.6125
0.7665
0.9645
0.9586
99


1
M
87
0.9651
0.1639
0.8682
0.9317
99


1
F
87
0.1760
0.5655
0.8608
0.2268
99


1
M
88
0.3845
0.1555
0.4391
0.9839
99


1
F
88
0.4303
0.4160
0.0244
0.1207
99


1
M
89
0.6917
0.5914
0.3941
0.6072
99


1
F
89
0.0138
0.1615
0.8786
0.0261
99


1
M
90
0.8866
0.3962
0.0222
0.7781
99


1
F
90
0.3363
0.9800
0.9433
0.1269
99


1
M
91
0.1554
0.1577
0.3882
0.6609
99


1
F
91
0.1513
0.2226
0.2839
0.8876
99


1
M
92
0.4778
0.6034
0.2255
0.2174
99


1
F
92
0.2869
0.2126
0.3219
0.7483
99


1
M
93
0.7612
0.1502
0.8764
0.4286
99


1
F
93
0.1139
0.0081
0.0495
0.0343
99


1
M
94
0.4445
0.7812
0.5316
0.9033
99


1
F
94
0.1434
0.9192
0.1609
0.2090
99


1
M
95
0.6710
0.9470
0.2734
0.5174
99


1
F
95
0.1107
0.1724
0.4663
0.6231
99


1
M
96
0.3294
0.7466
0.5839
0.6459
99


1
F
96
0.1723
0.7240
0.9257
0.9194
99


1
M
97
0.4197
0.4893
0.3920
0.0152
99


1
F
97
0.3773
0.1450
0.1009
0.8623
99


1
M
98
0.2608
0.2236
0.0567
0.9994
99


1
F
98
0.8237
0.9396
0.9435
0.0972
99


1
M
99
0.3362
0.8975
0.7197
0.9538
99


1
F
99
0.2978
0.1690
0.6472
0.9131
99



Table2:



time
age
rate
count




1
0
0.9186
592.6036


2
0
0.1821
348.5050


3
0
0.6390
614.7256


4
0
0.0010
436.2179


5
0
0.0564
210.4892


6
0
0.7611
102.9123


7
0
0.6026
19.3011


8
0
0.8797
740.2814


9
0
0.2265
73.3088


10
0
0.7781
677.1890


11
0
0.8934
470.9423


12
0
0.3311
126.8357


13
0
0.7768
470.7404


14
0
0.6377
373.7966


15
0
0.3310
363.2666


16
0
0.0989
263.2227


17
0
0.2262
899.3678


18
0
0.6758
850.3190


19
0
0.0795
375.0234


20
0
0.0313
798.3833


21
0
0.6403
836.1008


22
0
0.6588
194.9405


23
0
0.3495
495.7669


24
0
0.4776
881.4085


25
0
0.4060
910.6677


26
0
0.2872
998.1357


27
0
0.1339
199.5729


28
0
0.9256
35.7261


29
0
0.5947
367.9693


30
0
0.7794
786.0985


31
0
0.9921
567.1374


32
0
0.4354
430.7011


33
0
0.5089
916.2078


34
0
0.3393
959.1348


35
0
0.2520
376.0539


36
0
0.9811
327.8549


37
0
0.0652
310.2590


38
0
0.7446
88.2030


39
0
0.2361
792.6146


40
0
0.0098
884.7557


41
0
0.6527
374.9891


42
0
0.8880
982.3413


43
0
0.4050
91.2553


44
0
0.8614
134.5264


45
0
0.0505
822.5105


46
0
0.9598
852.7034


47
0
0.4384
608.7611


48
0
0.1027
972.2022


49
0
0.9015
50.5832


50
0
0.6869
758.5370


1
1
0.6229
159.8670


2
1
0.3103
464.5342


3
1
0.5768
572.2546


4
1
0.4288
662.2016


5
1
0.7404
411.9077


6
1
0.4239
74.7661


7
1
0.5745
6.6215


8
1
0.9828
570.4171


9
1
0.0363
495.1628


10
1
0.2748
485.6012


11
1
0.0957
787.2858


12
1
0.5418
40.5074


13
1
0.8890
28.6800


14
1
0.3865
142.5425


15
1
0.3380
524.6449


16
1
0.9551
368.3743


17
1
0.0511
955.0442


18
1
0.8489
284.5242


19
1
0.1242
778.9754


20
1
0.5084
886.2673


21
1
0.0490
907.3557


22
1
0.0451
598.0020


23
1
0.9809
312.8750


24
1
0.5665
120.6141


25
1
0.1277
65.5068


26
1
0.6375
385.6774


27
1
0.0683
180.5081


28
1
0.4111
685.8128


29
1
0.3615
405.8992


30
1
0.3085
89.0203


31
1
0.8391
507.5723


32
1
0.7462
18.0576


33
1
0.1333
446.9834


34
1
0.9174
716.4231


35
1
0.3866
616.6041


36
1
0.0568
870.5397


37
1
0.6257
172.1614


38
1
0.5044
705.5763


39
1
0.1776
659.6385


40
1
0.0062
335.9426


41
1
0.6652
975.6239


42
1
0.7963
896.4242


43
1
0.5331
320.2478


44
1
0.8697
497.7650


45
1
0.9644
90.7277


46
1
0.5386
752.0269


47
1
0.3644
781.5228


48
1
0.8632
705.6925


49
1
0.5288
785.3376


50
1
0.8860
169.8004



Basically, for a given age/state/sex, it creates a sumproduct value for the next 50 years of age and each of the time values matching that initial age (and the appropriate next age).  So the very first observation yields these 50 rows them the product column which is multiplying them. Sum of that product (sumproduct) = 564.7810.
Table3:



factor
weight
reduction
discount
rate
count
product




0.7957
0.4980
0.9170
0.4596
0.9186
592.6036
90.9004


0.5983
0.9033
0.5879
0.0524
0.1821
348.5050
1.0564


0.8212
0.1305
0.9636
0.9022
0.6390
614.7256
36.6094


0.6068
0.2600
0.3310
0.9246
0.0010
436.2179
0.0206


0.4023
0.8970
0.7233
0.8899
0.0564
210.4892
2.7556


0.8983
0.9794
0.9420
0.4846
0.7611
102.9123
31.4580


0.9268
0.9799
0.3462
0.3355
0.6026
19.3011
1.2271


0.5930
0.2939
0.7156
0.0472
0.8797
740.2814
3.8304


0.3694
0.3643
0.0273
0.7473
0.2265
73.3088
0.0457


0.6905
0.4604
0.1318
0.5900
0.7781
677.1890
13.0236


0.3149
0.8735
0.2050
0.6325
0.8934
470.9423
15.0028


0.2898
0.4101
0.0536
0.3884
0.3311
126.8357
0.1039


0.2871
0.3553
0.0799
0.8853
0.7768
470.7404
2.6397


0.4145
0.0722
0.6584
0.7030
0.6377
373.7966
3.3002


0.9767
0.7314
0.0115
0.2084
0.3310
363.2666
0.2052


0.5354
0.5422
0.2838
0.2006
0.0989
263.2227
0.4301


0.2456
0.0066
0.2436
0.5083
0.2262
899.3678
0.0406


0.4126
0.5348
0.5408
0.1089
0.6758
850.3190
7.4660


0.2292
0.8879
0.7626
0.1920
0.0795
375.0234
0.8886


0.7928
0.7069
0.1766
0.7200
0.0313
798.3833
1.7820


0.3414
0.6847
0.1112
0.1189
0.6403
836.1008
1.6533


0.7547
0.1034
0.6747
0.4381
0.6588
194.9405
2.9611


0.4329
0.0193
0.2065
0.0488
0.3495
495.7669
0.0146


0.3127
0.4153
0.3801
0.4435
0.4776
881.4085
9.2170


0.8590
0.8720
0.3075
0.3842
0.4060
910.6677
32.7273


0.2967
0.8740
0.8525
0.5149
0.2872
998.1357
32.6338


0.9432
0.2151
0.5174
0.9982
0.1339
199.5729
2.7987


0.2239
0.0513
0.5230
0.1895
0.9256
35.7261
0.0377


0.9120
0.1104
0.8375
0.4193
0.5947
367.9693
7.7351


0.7930
0.4171
0.3524
0.9897
0.7794
786.0985
70.6619


0.0008
0.1787
0.4106
0.8365
0.9921
567.1374
0.0268


0.1305
0.4952
0.4934
0.4547
0.4354
430.7011
2.7191


0.0631
0.4752
0.8618
0.0294
0.5089
916.2078
0.3544


0.6276
0.9440
0.8247
0.5009
0.3393
959.1348
79.6402


0.7205
0.8169
0.9580
0.3159
0.2520
376.0539
16.8826


0.9689
0.3198
0.1618
0.9052
0.9811
327.8549
14.5937


0.0951
0.0367
0.3816
0.0206
0.0652
310.2590
0.0006


0.3447
0.3749
0.6322
0.8062
0.7446
88.2030
4.3260


0.3115
0.3269
0.2346
0.4383
0.2361
792.6146
1.9601


0.2576
0.9518
0.7497
0.3449
0.0098
884.7557
0.5514


0.1279
0.1252
0.4894
0.9661
0.6527
374.9891
1.8522


0.6379
0.0242
0.0209
0.8563
0.8880
982.3413
0.2417


0.7912
0.5899
0.0024
0.3164
0.4050
91.2553
0.0133


0.4280
0.0754
0.8396
0.8048
0.8614
134.5264
2.5256


0.0845
0.0535
0.8778
0.4514
0.0505
822.5105
0.0743


0.3555
0.4436
0.6478
0.6568
0.9598
852.7034
54.9138


0.6532
0.5990
0.0813
0.4915
0.4384
608.7611
4.1715


0.1548
0.4953
0.6552
0.2235
0.1027
972.2022
1.1207


0.5892
0.6052
0.4248
0.1052
0.9015
50.5832
0.7268


0.7870
0.2494
0.3732
0.1273
0.6869
758.5370
4.8592



Unfortunately I just realized this breaks once I get beyond age 50 (probably due to array sizes) but it gets everything before that correct.  Pulling my hair out.

I think I understand now. For the first entry (Male, Age 0, Maxage = 49), you want to pull all the rows from Table 1 where (Sex = Male) and (Age between 0 & 49) and (State = 1, whatever that means). The, you want to pull all the rows from Table 2 where (Age = 0) and (Time ≤ 50). Those two pulls should have the same number of rows. Once you have all that, you want to set the tables side-by-side, get the product of each row, and finally return the sum of those products. I think this can be simpler. Which version of Excel are you using? Do you have the HSTACK function?

I'm new here, so this might not be necessary to add for folks, but for any future readers, this explanation is spot on.

Power Query
Here's suggestion using Power Query:

Import the two tables as Table1 and Table2
To get projection for one row add a blank query

(rowIndex as number) as number =>
  let
    row1 = Table1{rowIndex},
    tb1Rows = Table.SelectRows(
      Table1,
      each 
          [state] = row1[state]
        and [sex] = row1[sex]
        and [age] >= row1[age]
        and [age] <= row1[maxage]
    ),
    tb2Rows = Table.SelectRows(Table2, each [age] = row1[age] and [time] <= row1[maxage] + 1),
    tb1tb2Proj =
      if Table.RowCount(tb1Rows) > 0 and Table.RowCount(tb1Rows) = Table.RowCount(tb2Rows) then
        List.Accumulate(
          List.Numbers(0, Table.RowCount(tb1Rows)),
          0,
          (state, r) =>
            tb1Rows[factor]{r}
              * tb1Rows[weight]{r}
              * tb1Rows[reduction]{r}
              * tb1Rows[discount]{r}
              * tb2Rows[rate]{r}
              * tb2Rows[count]{r}
              + state
        )
      else
        0
  in
    tb1tb2Proj


Rename the query as tb1RowProj
Add another blank query

let
    Source = Table1,
    addedIndex = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    addedRowSum = Table.AddColumn(addedIndex, "rowSum", each tb1RowProj([Index])),
    keepRowSumCol = Table.SelectColumns(addedRowSum,{"rowSum"})
in
    keepRowSumCol


Rename this to a suitable one - I've used Table1Projections in the example

Close and Load the results back into Excel




Using helper columns:
In T2 for tb1_sum:
=LET(
    tb1_data, A2:H201,
    INDEX(tb1_data, , 4) * INDEX(tb1_data, , 5) * INDEX(tb1_data, , 6) *
        INDEX(tb1_data, , 7)
)

In V2 for tb2_sum:
=LET(tb2_data, K2:N101, INDEX(tb2_data, , 3) * INDEX(tb2_data, , 4))

For final results:
=LET(
    tb1_data, A2:H201,
    tb2_data, K2:N101,
    tb1_sum, T2#,
    tb2_sum, V2#,
    tb1_col, LAMBDA(name, XMATCH(name, A1:H1)),
    tb1_row_indices, SEQUENCE(ROWS(tb1_data)),
    state, INDEX(tb1_data, , tb1_col("state")),
    sex, INDEX(tb1_data, , tb1_col("sex")),
    age, INDEX(tb1_data, , tb1_col("age")),
    maxage, INDEX(tb1_data, , tb1_col("maxage")),
    tb2_col, LAMBDA(name, XMATCH(name, K1:N1)),
    tb2_row_indices, SEQUENCE(ROWS(tb2_data)),
    tb2_time, INDEX(tb2_data, , tb2_col("time")),
    tb2_age, INDEX(tb2_data, , tb2_col("age")),
    sum_for_tb1_row, LAMBDA(r,
        LET(
            tb1_filtered, FILTER(
                tb1_row_indices,
                (state = INDEX(state, r, 1)) * (sex = INDEX(sex, r, 1)) *
                    (age >= INDEX(age, r, 1)) * (age <= INDEX(maxage, r, 1))
            ),
            tb2_filtered, FILTER(
                tb2_row_indices,
                (tb2_age = INDEX(age, r, 1)) * (tb2_time <= INDEX(maxage, r, 1) + 1)
            ),
            row_sum, SUM(INDEX(tb1_sum, tb1_filtered) * INDEX(tb2_sum, tb2_filtered)),
            IFERROR(row_sum, "Rows don't match")
        )
    ),
    MAP(tb1_row_indices, sum_for_tb1_row)
)


I have absolutely no idea what this does, but it matches perfectly, and on the small example table is (basically) instant.  Normally, with enough push in the right direction I'd be able to take it the rest of the way, but you're using a handful of functions I've never used before.  I hate seeming needy, but ... when I tried taking that the rest of the way it crashed Excel a half dozen times.  So, please!  Also, the data are manual values, but I could use VBA, SQL Server, Power Query, whatever.  Request is/was for simple, but if it makes it significantly faster, I warned them it might not be.

No joy.  PQ or VBA I guess.  Math-wise, I can multiply the 4 values (factor, weight, reduction, discount) in table 1 for each observation.  For table 2 I can kind of do the same (the actual data requires some conditional use, but whatever).  Even then, there is age 0 to 100, 75 "states," 2 genders (also 3 different "groups" but I didn't include that in my sample data due to size constraints) in one table and projected out over (generally) 50 time values.  Expanding that in a sheet to just multiply and sum would be 2.2M rows and I'm guessing Excel isn't liking that.

No I didn't get any messages before it crashed other than it freezing.  I tried waiting it out once for an hour, but it still never finished so either it was still processing or it died.  I tried running something through VBA - not ideal - just to get a feel for it, but sumproduct requires using the worksheet function, without allowing for more than one negative condition.  Which meant loops in loops storing a temp result.  Also minutes to generate an output.  Trying PQ and/or helper columns.

They're mostly from CSVs but I moved them into the workbook instead of querying them.  Partly to save time (I hoped).  But some of the columns are calculated based on user choices.  For instance, reduction and discount both change based on values set elsewhere.  I'll just add something forcing a refresh.  This won't be doable via straight formulas.  PQ is chugging along slowly (which is better than crashing).

The biggest problem is that the fastest way to do this seems to be using a massive amount of OFFSET/INDIRECT formulas.  But those volatile functions mean every time you do anything it recalculates so it's a nightmare.  I'm wondering if it's best to just pass parameters to SQL Server and let it pull from there.

@jwcane, where do you have the volatile functions? You could export the values only (as CSV for example) and then use that as the basis to PQ.

Basically, the original version of this uses INDIRECT and/or OFFSET in ... I kid you not ... over 100k cells.  We received it from a vendor.  I'm trying to make it useable.  Are you suggesting (in essence) having one workbook work as a front-end, sending parameters to the volatile workbook and getting results?  It does get around the constantly recalculating, but that doesn't seem stable.

Yes. 1. Backup 2. For the sheets/tables for this task (I assume these are the ones with volatile formulas), save each sheet as CSV. 3. Import these into PQ (or Excel if you prefer) and perform the calculation (projections). 4. Feed the results back into where they need to be processed further. PQ is very helpful as you can verify each step, also for cleaning up data after CSV export/import.

It ended up creating a lot more difficulty since the original workbook has it spread across a lot more worksheets.  I'm trying SQL Server now.  I'll figure out how to pass the query conditions to SQL, but I created the base tables and it handles the actual sumproduct part we've been working on in ~12 seconds.  Just silly in comparison.  It means they can't edit things "live" but it's going to have to work.  PQ didn't complete after 30 minutes.  VBA took forever.  This is kind of an amazing technical exercise.  Thank you for all your help @nkalvi.

My pleasure @jwcane! Hopefully you can guide them for a better performing process.

I'm posting this as a wiki because it's not an answer; it's a request for clarification. I broke down your formula into bits to try to understand what's happening with your giant formulas. The screenshot below shows how far I got. There are follow-up questions at the end.

For the columns AA:AF, I took your LET formula and changed the output to just Array1A and then Array1B, etc. Each of those columns has the same LET formula but with a different output. This way, we can see the results of the various pieces before we try to sum their products. Below the bottom of this screenshot is a few thousand rows just like the last one here: several blanks and then some zeroes.
AH2 has the formula =PRODUCT(AA2:AF2) which I then copied straight down. I don't know if the product part of SUMPRODUCT operates differently than just the PRODUCT function.
Column AJ has various method of summing products.

sumproduct as written by OP is your exact LET function from above. Per Microsoft's documentation of SUMPRODUCT:


The array arguments must have the same dimensions. If they do not, SUMPRODUCT returns the #VALUE! error value.


sumproduct of entire columns here is a sumproduct of the entire column ranges: =SUMPRODUCT(AA2:AA5051,AB2:AB5051,AC2:AC5051,AD2:AD5051,AE2:AE5051,AF2:AF5051)
sum of "product" column here is a sum of the product column that I made: =SUM(AH2:AH5051)
sum of red box is a sum of just the part of the product column that has a red border around it: =SUM(AH2:AH16). I included this to show that it is the same result as the sumproduct of entire columns here formula above, probably because it interprets all the blank cells as zero so the product for that row is also zero.


With all that said, I still have no idea what you're trying to do. All of this has been just to get a value for the first row in Table 1. With the tables being different sizes, you can't use a regular sumproduct. You could make a sumproduct of the values from Table 1 (columns AA:AD in my screenshot) and a different sumproduct of the vales from Table 2 (columns AE:AF) and then multiply those two value but, again, I don't know what you want the result to be. I need clarification before I figure out how to help.
Can you work through an example of the step-by-step of what you expect to be happening for one row?

Thanks for your feedback!  Part of the issue is I didn't post enough data for things to work (and I just realized it doesn't work for the entirety of ages either)!  I added more data and a better explanation I hope.

Using the same method for referencing cells, this works:
=SUMPRODUCT(HSTACK(FILTER($D$2:$G$2801,($C$2:$C$2801>=$C2)*($C$2:$C$2801<=$H2)*($B$2:$B$2801=$B2)*($A$2:$A$2801=$A2)),FILTER(Sheet2!$C$2:$D$5051,(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5051<>"")*(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$5051=$C2)*(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5051<=$H2+1))))
Here are the major changes from your original:

FILTER can filter based on fields that aren't in the result. Instead of feeding in the entire table and then later having to weed out just the bits you need, just feed in columns D:G from Table 1 and C:D from Table 2. You can still filter based on the values in other columns but now the result is just the numbers you need.
Table 2 has an extra filter condition: (Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5051<>""). This cuts out all the blank rows you were / I was getting at the bottom. Table 1 C2 is zero and Excel treats blanks like zero so they were included in the results and threw off the number of rows. If your data is totally full for all 5050 rows, you may not need this bit.
HSTACK takes two arrays and merges them side-by-side into one array. This lets us feed a single array into the SUMPRODUCT. For future reference, VSTACK does the same thing but stacks them vertically, one below the other.


You can take this further by making them into real Tables in Excel. That lets you have more legible formulas like this:
=SUMPRODUCT(HSTACK(FILTER(Table1[[factor]:[discount]],([age]>=[@age])*([age]<=[@maxage])*([sex]=[@sex])*([state]=[@state])),FILTER(Table2[[rate]:[count]],(Table2[time]<>"")*(Table2[age]=[@age])*(Table2[time]<=[@maxage]+1))))
... and you can add the result right to the table (the CALC errors are because there aren't any ages above 1 in the sample of Table 2 so FILTER returns nothing):


Okay, I'm following with your logic - I hadn't thought about HSTACK / VSTACK, but that's a fantastic idea.  I have one concern though, which is that something in there has to be incorrect, since your interim results match mine, but the sumproduct value doesn't match what I had for row 1 (564.7810).
Also, yeah, Sheet2 does have 5051 rows (Sheet1 has ~45k).

Okay, I figured out why it's getting the incorrect answer, though I have no idea why it's true.  SUMPRODUCT apparently does not like the idea of receiving an A x B array and multiplying across columns.  Instead, it expects each array as A x 1.  I can cheat that a little bit by multiplying the columns across on both tables, but then I'll have to play around some more to get it to select each column separately.
